# How to clear unused materials in 2.79?

Tags: materials

I noticed Blender 2.79 doesn't show the "save & reload" option anymore.  I used to use that to clear any unused materials.  How can I do this?  I tried making all objects single users, the orphan add-on, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Hold SHIFT and click on the "X" in the Materials pane. Next time you open the .blend the material will be gone.

Comment: I don't think there was svae&reload function by default before 2.79, maybe it was just an addon which became disabled. This feature is present in [Amaranth Toolset addon](https://pablovazquez.art/amaranth/), called exactly as you wrote in the question

Comment: @MrZak interesting, I didn't realize it was in that addon.  I'm not sure how I got a version with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold SHIFT and click on the "X" in the Materials pane. Next time you open the .blend the material will be gone.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the other answer, if the material isn't assigned to anything, select "orphaned data" in the outliner and expand the "materials" category.  you can then right-click and delete any material you don't want anymore and it will be removed from the file immediately, no need to save and reopen.

Comment: Nice that's also a good method